# How i add rel="nofollow" on a tag in the ckeditor content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a site what user can submit content.So i want to avoid spam link by add on a tag rel="nofollow".How can i do that with jquery or php

```
<a href="http://mnking.net" rel="nofollow">This is link</a>
```

Comment: google about "regular expressions" and use one in your php code that handles user comments.

Comment: I think ,using regular exression is a best way

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$("a[href='http://mnking.net']").attr("rel", "nofollow");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you get the link using `$_POST`, you could use the following code (written in PHP):

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$tag = '<a href='.$url.'rel="nofollow">This is link</a>';
```

In PHP , the sign . (a simple dot) is used to concat strings.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("a").attr("rel", "nofollow");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put post into a separate div, let's say `class="post"`
and then just simple jquery code:

```
$('.post a').attr('rel', 'nofollow');
```